# Changing class using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc

In my HTML view page, I have written this on the section

```
 <div class="stats-small__data">
   <span class="stats-small__percentage stats-small__percentage--" id="SatisPrecent"></span>
 </div>
```

Also,  I created an ajax result to get value from the controller, and depending on that I want to add `increase` to the end of `stats-small__percentage stats-small__percentage--`

What I did was

```
 if (data.SatisAva > 50) {
   document.getElementById("SatisPrecent").className = "increase";
 } else {
   document.getElementById("SatisPrecent").className = "decrease";
 }
```

But it didn't work. Can any one help me on this please?

Comment: Instead of `className` you can try using `classList.add` and `classList.remove`.

Comment: the problem to me doesnt lay on using className... that's correct despite not being usually the preferred strategy. I think something is missing in the question. It says something didn't work but there's not enough information here to find out